# Main window appears behind other windows after splash screen

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Forms Application with a splash screen. When I run the application the splash screen shows up fine, disappears and the main form for the application is loaded.

However, when I load the main form it appears beneath the Windows Explorer directory which contains the application. Here is a segment of code that runs the splash screen and then the main form.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {        
        public Form1()
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SplashStart));
            t.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(1500);
            InitializeComponent();
            t.Abort();
        }        
        public void SplashStart()
        {
            Application.Run(new SplashScreen());
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get `Form1` to show above all other windows?

Comment: Trying using `TopMost` when the main form loads.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Don't use `TopMost`, it causes the window to **always** stay on top. You are doing a few things wrong here, using multiple `Application.Run` calls (there is one in the program.cs file), running another form on a thread, etc. Show the splash screen from the program.cs file, not from your main form, and there isn't any good reason to use a separate thread for it, in fact its not a good idea since UI items should be single-threaded and all operate on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks you so much Ron Beyer .. Using multiple Application.Run calls root cause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Form1.Activate();
```

This should make it the focus and bring to front.

MSDN link: [system windows forms form activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Use `form.BringToFront()` to put the form in front of everything else.